# i get a missing } after property list, while coding this program, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript

When i run this code, i get a `missing } after property list`

```
function task(a,b)
{

  alert(a);
  alert(b);

}

thread_job = {

init: function(func,param1,param2)
{
this.func = func
this.param1 = param1
this.param2 = param2
alert("inside init");
}


  run: function{

  this.func(this.param1,this.param2);

 }


 }


thread_job.init(task,1,2)
thread_job.run()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: 'think he's one of those who don't care about answers...

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close for this line:

```
thread_job = {
```

Also, you need to separate the items by a `,`:

```
function task(a, b) {

    alert(a);
    alert(b);

}

thread_job = {

    init: function (func, param1, param2) {
        this.func = func
        this.param1 = param1
        this.param2 = param2
        alert("inside init");
    },

    run: function {
        this.func(this.param1, this.param2);
    }
}


thread_job.init(task, 1, 2);
thread_job.run();
```

> Always don't forget to **format your code** to make it readable!

Comment: also missing commas between object elements

Comment: @MightyPork yes yes, I found out. Updated the answer. :)